Proof that a convergent algorithm for a well-posed problem is stable
This question is based on an observation in Chapter 1 of Analysis of Numerical Methods by Isaacson and Keller: If a mathematical problem is well-posed and the algorithm to solve the problem is convergent, then the algorithm must also be well-posed.
In their notation, let $y = g(a)$ be a well-posed mathematical problem. Well-posed means that given data in some domain, $a \in D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we have a function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which gives us a unique solution $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ to the problem, and additionally $g$ must be Lipschitz continuous at each point in the domain.
Since we may not be able to solve the problem directly, we choose an algorithm defined by another function $x = f(a)$. In this case, $x$ is an approximation to the actual solution $y$. We say that the algorithm is convergent if for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall \left\lVert \delta a \right\rVert < \delta$, we have $\left\lVert f(a + \delta a) - g(a + \delta a) \right\rVert < \epsilon$. We say the algorithm is well-posed (or stable) using the same definition as above.
If we assume that we have a well-posed problem and the algorithm is convergent, then for small enough $\left\lVert \delta a \right\rVert$, and letting $N$ be the Lipschitz constant for $g$, we have
$$
\left\lVert f(a + \delta a) - f(a) \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert f(a + \delta a) - g(a + \delta a) \right\rVert + \left\lVert g(a + \delta a) - g(a) \right\rVert + \left\lVert g(a) - f(a) \right\rVert \\
\leq \epsilon + N \left\lVert \delta a \right\rVert + \epsilon
$$
Isaacson and Keller then say that we can use this computation to show that $f$ itself is Lipschitz continuous, and therefore the algorithm is well-posed as well. I was wondering how we can prove Lipschitz continuity of $f$ from the above computation—it seems that the $\epsilon$ parameter would prevent this.
